# Prolog prefix sum of a list

Tags: list, sum, prolog, prefix

I want to implement the prolog predicate `prefixSum(L, R)` that calculates the prefix sum of a list i.e:

```
?- prefixSum([1,2,3,4],R).
R=[1,3,6,10].
```

Here is my solution so far:

```
prefixSum([],[]).
prefixSum([X], [X])
prefixSum([X|Xs], [R, Rs|T]):- 
    Rs is X + R,  prefixSum(Xs, T).
```

What can I try next?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: @Enigmativity "it doesn't work" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prefix_sum(L, Ps) :-
    prefix_sum_(L, 0, Ps).
    
prefix_sum_([], _, []).
prefix_sum_([H|T], S, [P|Ps]) :-
    P is H + S,
    prefix_sum_(T, P, Ps).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- prefix_sum([1,2,3,4], Ps).
Ps = [1, 3, 6, 10].
```

Comment: Of course, this is just a scan. See my answer and the provided link.

Comment: While this does a better job of showing the OP how to solve their problem, it just doesn't explain what the OP did wrong or how and why this solution works.

Comment: "why this solution works" @Enigmativity it works because it is correct while the one by OP is not.

Comment: @TA_intern - How would we know that the OP's code doesn't work and this solution works? Both have just posted code with no clear explanation. This is a poor question/answer combination. Our job, as members of this community, is to raise the quality of both the questions and answers on this site. Stack Overflow exists to create a repository of quality questions and answers ***for future readers***. Future readers are unlikely to run the OP's code and say "Ah, I see why it's not working" and even if they run this code they may be still none-the-wiser as to why this works.

Comment: @brebs oof shots fired :-D

Answer (score 1):

Your original code,

```
prefixSum( []     , []       ) .
prefixSum( [X]    , [X]      )
prefixSum( [X|Xs] , [R,Rs|T] ) :- Rs is X+R, prefixSum(Xs,T) .
```

Has these problems:

- The code is syntactically incorrect, as the 2nd clause is not terminated by `.`.
- In the 3rd clause, the variable `R` will **always** be unbound unless you've provided a bound list as the 2nd argument to `prefixSum/3`, meaning `Rs is X+R` will fail.

The key to what you are trying to accomplish is that as you traverse the list, you need to track the sum previously computed as you go.

That leads to an implementation like this:

```
prefix_sum( []     , []     ) .  % the empty list is a special case
prefix_sum( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- % for a non-empty list, we add the first item to the result , and
  prefix_sum(Xs,X,Ys) .          % invoke our helper, seeding the previous sum with the first element.

prefix_sum( []     , _ , []     ) .  % once the source list is exhausted, we're done.
prefix_sum( [X|Xs] , P , [Y|Ys] ) :- % otherwise...
  Y is P+X,                          % compute the sum of the current element and the previous sum
  prefix_sum(Xs,Y,Ys) .              % and recurse down on the tails.
```

Comment: @TA_intern — I believe the downvote was per this comment: "_**While this does a better job of showing the OP how to solve their problem, it just doesn't explain what the OP did wrong or how and why this solution works.**_" Often, newbie questions, in particular regarding Prolog, is as much or more about simply grokking recursion and getting a handle on the language itself, Prolog being. . . . different than 95% of programming languages. And that being the case, solutions using library code aren't terribly useful: they're learning first principles.

Comment: No, Prolog is not that different. It really isn't. It has a well defined procedural reading; I would even dare to say that it isn't so difficult to grok that procedural reading. Repeating this mantra about Prolog has done enough damage already.

Answer (score 0):

This is an operation on lists knows as a "scan" which, unlike a "fold", keeps a list of intermediate results. For your particular case you could use the built-in plus/3 but you might also need to define a helper predicate like add/3:

```
add(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X + Y.
```

Now you can do:

```
?- foldl(add, [1,2,3,4], 0, Sum).
Sum = 10.

?- scanl(add, [1,2,3,4], 0, [0|Sums]).
Sums = [1, 3, 6, 10].
```

If you don't like the useless addition of the zero you can split off the first element in advance, so:

```
?- [1,2,3,4] = [V0|Vs], scanl(add, Vs, V0, Result).
V0 = 1,
Vs = [2, 3, 4],
Result = [1, 3, 6, 10].
```

"Scan left" and "fold left" are available in library(apply) in SWI-Prolog and *your exact question* is solved in the examples on the [docs for scanl](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=scanl/4). You can also look at the [implementation of scanl](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/apply.pl?show=src#scanl/4).

Yes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75344567/14411997) is perfectly good. When I look at the solution and compare it to the library definition of scanl/4 I just see a generic algorithm that has been specialized to solve one particular instance by binding the Goal.

Comment: Pro tip: note that phrases like "the answer above" or "the accepted answer" may not stand the test of time, since answers can reorder and the OP can change the acceptance mark. It is usually better to say "the answer from brebs", since answer authors nearly always write just one answer. Alternatively you can link to an answer using the Share link.

Comment: While this may provide an alternative approach for the OP is does ***not***, in my opinion, answer the question. The OP is asking how to get their predicate right. They are learning how to code in Prolog. They aren't trying to actually get the result.

Comment: @brebs - They appear to be trying to learn how to get the result. The result itself isn't the goal. And it's not bizarre downvoting. There are many good posts on what downvoting is used for. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/guide-for-upvoting-and-downvoting https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/guide-for-upvoting-and-downvoting https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers

Comment: @Enigmativity "They appear to be trying to learn how to get the result." Yes, exactly. So I provided an answer that puts their question in context, offers alternative ways to look at it, and carefully nudges to a systematic way of tackling such problems in the future: Solve your problem correctly with a library predicate, then look at the library implementation, then figure out how to get from that generic algorithm to your specific solution. But somehow, **this isn't good enough**. :-)